# Pattern Matching/Checking Arity of Function1

Tags: scala

Given the following method:

```
scala> def f: List[Any] => Any = xs => 1234 // this output does not matter
f: List[Any] => Any
```

Is it possible to pattern match on `List[Any] => Any`? I don't see an `unapply` method on [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1), so I believe the answer is no.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Example:

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match { 
   case ... // to handle the case of List[Any] => Any]?
   case ...
}
```

Perhaps I can figure out the `arity` of `x: Any` to differentiate between `List[Any] => Any` versus everything else (`_`)?

**EDIT**:

I hope that I do not have to rely on `f.toString` == `<function1>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't match exactly on `List[Any] => Any` due to type erasure, but you can match on `Function1` itself:

```
def foo(x: Any): String = x match {
    case _: Function1[_, _] => "some function1"
    case _ => "other"
}
```

Any other matching, like `case _: (List[Any] => Any) => "function from list to any"` will act the same as `case _: Function1[_, _] => "some function"`:

```
scala> def foo(x: Any): String = x match {
     |     case _: (List[Any] => Any) => "function from list to any"
     |     case _ => "other"
     | }
<console>:8: warning: non-variable type argument List[Any] in type pattern List[Any] => Any is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case _: (List[Any] => Any) => "function from list to any"
                              ^
foo: (x: Any)String

scala> def aaa(l: Any): Any = null //it's `Any => Any` - not `List[Any] => Any`!!
aaa: (l: Any)Any

scala> foo(aaa _)
res11: String = function from list to any

scala> foo(1)
res12: String = other
```

Comment: Thanks. As an aside, I added another `sealed trait` and 2 `case class`'es, one of which had a `Function1[Any, Any]` parameter. That prevented me from casting.

Answer (score 3):

You can match purely on type, even without an `unapply` method:

```
def foo(x: Any): String = x match {
    case _: (Any => Any) => "some function1"
    case _ => "other"
}
```

And then you can check:

```
foo(f) //"some function1"
foo(1) //"other"
```